# Less than or equal to a specified date

Tags: date

I am trying to write a query to get records where the date <= specified date. The data table has the date in `DDMMMYY` format, eg. 14AUG15.

My query is:

```
create table enrol_crse as
select distinct id, count(distinct id) as count
from enrol_crse2
where term = '1159'
and enrl_add_date <= '21SEP15';
```

I get the error:

> Expression using less than or equal has components that are of
>   different type.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Can you show the full query and add your flavour of SQL to the tags?

Comment: `The data table has the date in "DDMMMYY" format` it's much much better to use the native date type as comparisons will then work as expected

Comment: almost certainly your date value is stored as a string, and you're trying to do `date <= string`, which isn't going to work.

Comment: The underlying data table has the date in the "DDMMMYY" format, eg. 14AUG15 and I don't have rights to change it

Answer (score 0):

A query that you already tried would have been appreciated but maybe you want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE date <= '14-AUG-15'
```

Change the format of the date according to how it exactly appears in your table.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving that error because you are comparing two values that are different types: You are comparing a `string` against a native `date` type.

To perform this comparison, you have to compare a `date` against another `date`. So:

1. **If your date column stores `string` values,** convert these values to `date` types *inside your expression*. How to do this will differ from database to database, but might look like: `... WHERE CAST(enrl_add_date AS DATE) <= some_date_value`
2. **If your date column *does not* store `string` values,** then your "specified date" -- the value you compare against the field -- is not a date, and your database needs you to explicitly convert it to a date. Similar to above, this might look like: `...WHERE enrl_date_add <= CAST(some_date_value AS DATE)`

Comment: I looked at the underlying data and the column enrl_add_date shows type as number and format as date. Tried both ways as you suggested and still have errors.